# How do I put my random generated word into an variable?

Tags: bash, unix

I made a script that prints a random word from /usr/share/dict/words.
I want it to store the random word into a variable, but I can't figure it out..

The script is as followed:

```
ALL_NON_RANDOM_WORDS=/usr/share/dict/words

# total number of non-random words available 
non_random_words=`cat $ALL_NON_RANDOM_WORDS | wc -l` 

random_number=`od -N3 -An -i /dev/urandom | 
awk -v f=0 -v r="$non_random_words" '{printf "%i\n", f + r * $1 /   16777216}'` 
sed `echo $random_number`"q;d" $ALL_NON_RANDOM_WORDS
```

I tried several things but got errors like access denied etc..

Comment: Try running `wc -l /usr/share/dict/words` on the command line, as the same user that executes the script. If that works without a permission issue than try hitting `/dev/urandom` as well with something like `head /dev/urandom`. That will help nail down where `access denied` error is coming from.

Comment: The error is gone, now I get not found.. I just want to store the random word in a char array so I can use it later for comparing chars

Answer (score 0):

If you got a `access denied`, it *may* mean that you have no permission to visit something. So you may try as this: `sudo yourScript`

By the way, please give us the *full* error message.

Comment: Well, if i try: 
WORD=sed `echo $random_number`"q;d"$ALL_NON_RANDOM_WORDS 
It gives me: not found

Comment: @Mirwais r u sure that you have stored the `words` file properly?

Comment: Yes because it is a standard dictionary in every unix system